# Obtaining numerical values from the mnewton function of the Maxima program

Tags: maxima

I use Maxima for calculations. I solve a system of nonlinear equations using Newton's method (mnewton()). I get the solution in the form of a list:
[[φ2=5.921818183272879,s=5.155870949147037]]
How to get the numerical value of the first (φ2) and second (s) unknown. If I substitute:
x: roz1[[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nAo8u.png)][2]$
I get that x is equal to: s=5.155870949147037
What to do to make x equal to a numerical value only: 5.155870949147037
(without s=).
My code:
[Maxima code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nAo8u.png)

Answer (score 1):

I have two ideas. (1) You can call `rhs` to return the right-hand side of an equation (likewise `lhs` for the left-hand side). E.g. `rhs(s = 123)` returns `123`.

(2) You can call `assoc` to find the value associated with `s` (or any variable) in the `mnewton` results. E.g. `assoc('s, [a = 1, b = 2, s = 3, u = 5])` returns `3`.

I like (2) better since it is not necessary to know where in the list is the one that you're interested in.